# Displaying SQL Query in HTML table (php)

Tags: php, html, mysql, count

Trying to get counts from 2 different tables into a simple HTML table.

This is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tasks";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) { ?>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Total</th> 
  </tr>
  <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?=$rowcount;?></td> 
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>

<?php } else { echo "0 results"; } ?>
```

When I run the code, it shows the amount of rows in the table, but it also creates the amount of rows with the number in it (i.e. 281 rows).

| Table |
| --- |
| 281 |
| 281 |
| 281 |
| 281 etc. |

My idea was to copy and paste the above to show a second table set of results (if it was correct), but is there a better way of doing this? I've been looking at how I would display `SELECT (select COUNT(*) from tasks) , (select count(*) from quotes)`  into the following format (HTML):

| Table | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Tasks | 281 |
| Quotes | 42000 |

Comment: `it also creates the amount of rows with the number in it`...the code you've shown does not seem able to do that. SELECT COUNT will always return exactly one row, unless there's also a GROUP BY in the query. You must be mistaken somehow. Also `mysqli_num_rows` would return `1`, not `281`. I suspect what you've shown in the table is actually the result of running the same PHP code, but the SQL must have been something like `SELECT * FROM tasks` instead. That would make sense with what you've shown (because you'd just be telling it to repeat `$rowcount` as many times as there are rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've been looking at how I would display SELECT (select COUNT(*) from
> tasks) , (select count(*) from quotes) into the following format
> (HTML)

You can just run the queries query, and use the result of the first to create the first row of the table, then the result of the second to create the second row. Since COUNT queries always return exactly 1 row when there's no GROUP BY, it's quite simple to do really:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tasks";
$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
if ($row = $result1->fetch_array()) $taskCount = $row[0];
else $taskCount = "error";

$sql2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quotes";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
if ($row = $result2->fetch_array()) $quoteCount = $row[0];
else $quoteCount = "error";

?>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Table</th> 
    <th>Count</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Tasks</td>
    <td><?php echo $taskCount; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Quotes</td>
    <td><?php echo $quoteCount; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Another way, if you want the HTML structure to be less repetitive / dependent on the tables queries, is to `UNION` the `SELECT`s into a single query:

```
$sql = "SELECT 'Tasks' AS 'table', COUNT(*) as 'count' FROM tasks";
$sql .= " UNION ";
$sql .= "SELECT 'Quotes' AS 'table', COUNT(*) as 'count' FROM quotes";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Table</th> 
    <th>Count</th> 
  </tr>
<?php
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["table"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["count"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php 
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: UNION query will fail if one of the tables is inaccessible (i.e. doesn't exist).

Comment: @Jared any query will fail if one of the tables named in it doesn't exist (not just UNION). What's your point? I think we have to assume the programmer knows what tables are in the application's database.

Comment: With a single UNION query you will get a single fail and no usefull data (except the fact something went wrong). With 10 separate queries vs 9 real tables and one non-existent you will get info on 9 tables (and one fail of course).

Comment: @Jared `no usefull data (except the fact something went wrong)` ...why do you think that? If you have mysqli error reporting on, you'll get an accurate message back from MySQL telling you which table was the problem - demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d7f0d5c3cacfe4d014340bf649e19a3f . But I think it's a tiny risk anyway - if the application cannot rely on the database tables existing at runtime then it's an unstable and poorly-designed application. If the programmer listed them in the code, they need to exist, otherwise it would fail testing and not be deployable.

Comment: Yes, the server will tell us what exactly went wrong, thats understood. In one situation we might need info on all the tables listed and even one fail will devaluate the whole result. In the other we don't want to run 1k queries for 1k tables. In the third we might not care about some missing tables (i.e. different schema version) and info on existing is enough. In the forth we will take table names from the schema and will not care bout typos or smthn. Using UNION is not just ok in some cases, but mandatory. And is absolutely unacceptable in the others. It depends on the goals.

Comment: @Jared you're massively overthinking it. the OP asked about two specific tables which they know about, and an easy way to list them in a table. No-one asked for a generic solution to look in any possible unknown database with different versions etc. There's no need for premature optimisation to cover a situation which will probably never be implemented. Anyway if OP is worried they can use my first solution, or yours.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your query does produces only one row for a table, not 281.
The second - I omit usage of prepared SQL statements with placeholders, which should always be used in a real project whenever applyable.

```
$rows = [];
foreach(['Tasks', 'Quotes'] as $table ){
    $result = $conn->query("SELECT '$table' as 'table', count(*) as 'count' FROM $table");
    if( $result ) 
        $rows[] = $result->fetch_assoc();
}

if( empty( $rows ) )
    print "0 results";
else {?>
    <table style="width:100%">
        <tr><th>Table</th><th>Count</th></tr>
        <?=implode(
            "\n", 
            array_map(function($row){
                return "<tr><td>${row['table']}</td><td>${row['count']}</td></tr>";
            }, $rows)
        )?>
    </table>
<?php }
```

Comment: `I omit usage of prepared SQL statements with placeholders`...you can't parameterise table names anyway, and there's no user-generated input going on, so it's irrelevant.

Comment: `you can't parameterise table names anyway` - yes, thats why i say `whenever applyable`; Thinking of parameterised prepared queries is always relevant. Cause next feature request may turn safe data into user input.

Comment: If the user is being asked to select table names then they need to be whitelisted and proxied in the data submission using an ID or something - the name would never be sent directly from the client-side, or go directly into the query from input variables. And since the same name here is also being used in the parameterisable part of the query, with that in place there'd still be no danger. It's different if the user was able to set their own label of course, but that isn't happening here. And you could still avoid it by not sending the label via SQL, and just outputting it direct from the PHP.

Comment: I'm talking about a common approach. In this particular situation with unparameterisable table names this could be a localhosted quick-and-dirty one shot tool with the only one user - programmer himself, so no security is required. If it is a somewhat public service, yes, we gonna need whitelists, ACL's, etc. And in a common case, using parameterised prepared queries is the first option programmer should think about; whenever applyable ofc.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "common case". Prepared statements and parameterised queries are useful in certain situations (e.g. when input comes externally, and/or when the same query will be repeated multiple times with different parameter values bound each time). If neither those scenarios apply, then it doesn't matter if they're not used. You're extrapolating the scenario way beyond what was specified in the requirements. The OP asked about listing the contents of two specific, pre-defined tables.